# I am getting two errors while compiling this java code

Tags: java

So i am getting these two errors. How can I solve them? and one more thing can anyone give me short code for variable c.

```
 double bucky[]= {7.8,5.9,4.1};
    double test[]= {0,0,0};

    for(int counter=0;counter<bucky.length;counter++){
        double c=(12-(test[0]*bucky[0]+test[1]*bucky[1]+test[2]*bucky[2]))/bucky[counter];

        int x= (int) c;
        test[counter]=x;
        System.out.println(test[counter]);

    }

        double summation=test[0]*bucky[0]+test[1]*bucky[1]+test[2]*bucky[2];

        double loss=12-summation;
       System.out.println("Loss is "+ loss);

int level=2;
if(test[level]>0){
    for(int jass=0;jass<(1-level);jass++){
        double test2[];
        double test2[jass]=test[jass];
        System.out.println("level after "+ test2[jass]);
    }

}
 else{
        System.out.println("not less");
    }
```

[image]

Still Nothing happens loop doesn't work.
     double bucky[]= {50,40,30,20};
        double test[]= {0,0,0,0};

```
    for(int counter=0;counter<bucky.length;counter++){
        double c=(130-(test[0]*bucky[0]+test[1]*bucky[1]+test[2]*bucky[2]+test[3]*bucky[3]))/bucky[counter];

        int x= (int) c;
        test[counter]=x;
        System.out.println(test[counter]);

    }

        double summation=test[0]*bucky[0]+test[1]*bucky[1]+test[2]*bucky[2]+test[3]*bucky[3];

        double loss=130-summation;
       System.out.println("Loss is "+ loss);

int level=2;
if(test[level]>0){
    double test2[] = new double[test.length];
    for(int jass=0;jass<(1-level);jass++){

         test2[jass]=test[jass];
        System.out.println("level after "+ test2[jass]);
    }

}
 else{
        System.out.println("not less");
    }
```

Comment: Well your syntax is wrong. Re-read up on how to declare and reference arrays in Java.

Comment: Try to explain what are you trying to do here `double test2[]; double test2[jass]=test[jass];`.

Comment: The logic in that loop doesn't make sense to me.  Why are you declaring an array in the first place?  All that loop does is print out values.  So just print them.  There's no need for that `test2` array at all.

Comment: That loop with `test2` shouldn't even run - level is set to 2, so the loop starts 0 and shall always be smaller -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for declaring and using an array would be something like:

```
double[] test2 = new double[someLengthValue];
test2[someIndex] = someValue;
```

But the whole thing is kind of moot, really.  In your loop you re-declare a new array every iteration and try to set a single value in that array.  Then all you do is print that value.  You don't need that array at all:

```
for(int jass=0;jass<(1-level);jass++){
    System.out.println("level after "+ test[jass]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still have some problem can you check that edit in post.

Comment: @DeepHypnosis: "Nothing happens" and "doesn't work" aren't really helpful descriptions of a problem.  This sounds like a great opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  You can step through the code, line by line, as it executes and examine the runtime values and behavior of the system.  This would allow you to identify specifically where the code is doing something you don't expect it to, and what the values of your variables and objects are when that happens.